# Getting value of host from ejabberd.yml file

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

How can we get value from ejabberd.yml file .also can we set values of ejabberd.yml from our written function in ejabberd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be get by Host=?MYHOSTS.?MYHOSTS is a Macro in erlang...